# How to find the shortest path going through some specified vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a grid graph

```
g = GridGraph[{12, 12}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can find a shortest from 1 to 144

```
path = FindShortestPath[g, 1, 144];
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[path]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But my question is how to find the shortest path from 1 to 144 and in the meantime this path go through vertex 50, 64, 103.

---

The post have not the demand of the order.And I havenot mention it before too.So update this case.

Comment: As stated that seems like it will be quite a few paths.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for point out.I have update the question just now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the vertices `v = {1, 50, 64, 103, 144}` are to be visited in the specified order, you can use

```
subpaths = Partition[v, 2, 1]
```

> {{1, 50}, {50, 64}, {64, 103}, {103, 144}}

```
fullpath = DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ FindShortestPath@g @@@ subpaths]
```

> {1, 2, 14, 26, 38, 50, 51, 52, 64, 65, 66, 67, 79, 91, 103, 104, 105,    106, 107, 108, 120, 132, 144}

```
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[fullpath], ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, you can get the same result defining a function:

```
pathF[g_Graph] := DeleteDuplicates[Developer`PartitionMap[
                      ##&@@ FindShortestPath@g@@# &, #, 2, 1]] &;
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[pathF[g][v]], ImagePadding -> 20]
```

Comment: Does this allow for the possibility that the shortest path may not go in precisely the order $1\rightarrow50\rightarrow64\rightarrow103\rightarrow144$?

Comment: @QuantumDot, very good point; it doesn't.

Comment: Oh,sorry the order isn't required.I will updat this.In any case,you are very good at this.:)