# Shortest path through more than two points visiting vertices once

Tags: graphs-and-networks, pathfinding

`FindShortestPath` works only with two points.

Is there a function that finds shortest path among more than two vertices in specified order and never visiting any vertex more than once?
For example we could have vertices `{v1,v2,v3,v4}`.

If you think the problem is equivalent to finding shortest paths between consecutive pairs of vertices (`{v1,v2},{v2,v3},{v3,v4}`) and then combining them (like it seems they assumed it here - [How to find the shortest path going through some specified vertices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111190/how-to-find-the-shortest-path-going-through-some-specified-vertices)) then I provide you with a counterexample.

Here is edge list of the counterexample graph.

```
UndirectedEdge@@@{{1,2},{1,3},{2,18},{3,18},{2,5},{3,4},{5,6},{5,7},{6,7},{6,9},{7,9},{9,10},{18,8},{4,8},{8,11},{8,21},{10,15},{15,11},{11,12},{12,13},{12,14},{13,16},{13,17},{16,17},{14,16},{21,17},{13,21},{4,7},{8,19},{19,10},{7,19},{14,17},{16,21},{1,20},{2,20},{3,20},{18,20}}
```

And here are all shortest paths from `1`, through `15`, to `21` of length `9`.

[image]

None of these paths can be created by combining shortest paths between `1` and `15` and between `15` and `21`.

**Update - Another example:**

Edge list:

```
UndirectedEdge@@@{{2,7},{2,25},{3,4},{3,15},{3,20},{4,13},{4,15},{5,10},{5,15},{7,15},{7,17},{7,25},{7,27},{8,14},{8,19},{8,20},{8,21},{8,22},{9,10},{9,23},{10,25},{13,19},{13,24},{14,21},{17,18},{17,30},{18,24},{19,23},{20,27},{21,26},{22,30},{23,27},{24,26},{25,27},{26,30}}
```

The unique shortest path from `5`, through `17`, to `15`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If timing doesn't matter, here's the brute force method:

```
g = Graph[
   UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 18}, {3, 18}, {2, 5}, {3, 
      4}, {5, 6}, {5, 7}, {6, 7}, {6, 9}, {7, 9}, {9, 10}, {18, 
      8}, {4, 8}, {8, 11}, {8, 21}, {10, 15}, {15, 11}, {11, 12}, {12,
       13}, {12, 14}, {13, 16}, {13, 17}, {16, 17}, {14, 16}, {21, 
      17}, {13, 21}, {4, 7}, {8, 19}, {19, 10}, {7, 19}, {14, 
      17}, {16, 21}, {1, 20}, {2, 20}, {3, 20}, {18, 20}}
   , VertexLabels -> Automatic];

v = {1, 15, 21};
subpaths = Partition[v, 2, 1];
minbound = 
  Total[Length[Most[#]] & /@ FindShortestPath@g @@@ subpaths];

Until[Length[res] > 0, 
 paths = FindPath[g, v[[1]], v[[-1]], {minbound++}, All]; 
 res = Pick[paths, MatchQ[#, Riffle[v, ___]] & /@ paths];

res
```

> {{1, 3, 4, 7, 19, 10, 15, 11, 8, 21}, {1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 15, 11, 8,
> 21}, {1, 2, 5, 7, 19, 10, 15, 11, 8, 21}, {1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 10, 15,
> 11, 8, 21}, {1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 15, 11, 8, 21}}

Comment: Similar, how I found the paths. No need to use `MatchQ`, more easy is to test whether the path contains `v[[2]]` - `Select[paths, MemberQ[#, v[[2]]] &]`.

Comment: Yes, if you have only one in the middle. MatchQ is for general case like more than 4 consecutive points.

Comment: Then `Riffle[v, ___]` is sufficient instead of `Riffle[v, ___, {1, -1, 2}]`.

Comment: That's correct.  edited