# Find a certain path through a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, graphs-and-networks

I would like to get a functional solution and nice display form for the following problem:

**1. Example data**

```
list =
  {
   {0, 1, 4, 8, 9, 1},
   {0, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3},
   {0, 8, 6, 1, 3, 2},
   {0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1},
   {0, 2, 9, 2, 7, 3},
   {0, 2, 1, 7, 2, 3}
   };
```

**2. Rules**

1. We start with a rectangular matrix with left-prepended zeros
2. Traversing the first matrix row from left to right, we search the
   first minimum (1 at position 2), mark it red and put it in a bag.
3. We continue with the 2nd row and find its first minimum not yet
   taken, which is 3 (1 is already in the bag).
4. The lowest **new** number in the third row is 2.
5. Arriving at the 4th row we find that all its distinct numbers are already in the bag. Therefore we mark the 0.
6. Zero is the only element which can be marked more than once, which can be seen in the last row.

**3. Expected result**

[image]

**4. Final display**

The final display should also show the path, not just the red elements like in the above matrix. It could be for example a `GridGraph` like shown in kglr's answer to

[How to find the shortest path going through some specified vertices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111190/how-to-find-the-shortest-path-going-through-some-specified-vertices)

But I would also welcome other display forms.

Comment: Is this really a graph theory problem?

Comment: No - I added the tag because of the possible display forms (Point 4 of the question).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update 2:** An alternative method using [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html):

```
step = Append[#, Min @ Complement[#2, #] /. Infinity -> 0] &;

unseenMins = Fold[step] @ Prepend[{}] @ #[[All, 2 ;;]] &;

unseenMinPositions = MapThread[{#, First @ #2 @ #3} &] @ 
 {Range @ Length @ #, Map[PositionIndex] @ #, unseenMins @ #} &;


unseenMinPositions @ list
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 1}}
> ```

**Original answer:**

```
highlightPositions =  Module[{$x = {}}, 
  MapIndexed[Flatten @ {#2[[1]], 1 + #} &]@
   Map[FirstPosition[#, 
    Last[AppendTo[$x, Min @ DeleteCases[Alternatives @@ $x] @ #]], {0}] &] @
       #[[All, 2 ;;]]] &;

MapAt[Style[#, Red,  Bold] &, list, highlightPositions @ list] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
positions = highlightPositions @ list;

gridgraph = GridGraph[Dimensions @ list, 
   VertexSize -> Large, 
   VertexLabelStyle -> 14, 
   VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[Times @@ Dimensions[list]] -> 
     Map[Placed[#, Center] &] @ 
     Apply[Join] @ Map[Reverse] @ Transpose @ list]]


PathGraph[positions, 
 VertexCoordinates -> ({#, 1 + Dimensions[list][[2]] - #2} & @@@ 
    Reverse /@ positions),
 EdgeStyle -> Thick, VertexSize -> Large, 
 VertexStyle -> Red, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[White, 16], 
 VertexLabels -> (Thread[# -> (Placed[#, Center] & /@ 
    Extract[list, #])] & @ positions), 
 Prolog -> First[Show @ gridgraph]]
```

[image]

**Update:**

An alternative approach using [`NearestNeighborGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestNeighborGraph.html) and [`FindShortestPath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestPath.html):

```
vertexlist = Tuples @ Range @ Dimensions @ list;

vcoords = Thread[Map[Reverse] @ vertexlist -> 
    SortBy[{First @ #, -Last @ #} &] @ vertexlist];

positions = highlightPositions @ list;

nng = NearestNeighborGraph[vertexlist, 
  VertexCoordinates -> vcoords,
  VertexSize -> Large,
   VertexStyle -> {v : Alternatives @@ positions -> Red},
  VertexLabelStyle -> {v : Alternatives @@ positions -> 
     Directive[16, White, Bold]},
  VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[list[[## & @@ v]], Center]}]
```

[image]

Highlight shortest paths between pairs in `positions`:

```
HighlightGraph[nng, 
 MapThread[Style[EdgeList[PathGraph@FindShortestPath[nng, ## & @@ #]], #2, 
     AbsoluteThickness[5]] &] @ 
 {Partition[positions, 2, 1], 
   Take[ 
    GraphComputation`GraphInformationDump`$AutomaticColorList,
    -1 + Length@positions]}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 , but it seems that the black vertex labels are not correct. For example, the first row should read 0, 1, 4, 8, 9, 1

Comment: @eldo, fixed the labels.

Comment: It seems that `tuples` isn't defined: vcoords = Thread[Map[Reverse] @ vertexlist ->  SortBy[{First @ #, -Last @ #} &] @ tuples];

Comment: thank you @eldo. It should be `vertexlist`. Updated with the correction.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it:

```
bag = {}; dim = Dimensions[list][[1]];
positions = MapThread[i = 0;
{++i, Splice@FirstPosition[#1, #2]} &
   , {list, 
    Last[AppendTo[bag, Min[Complement[#, bag]]] & /@ 
       list[[All, 2 ;;]]] /. Infinity -> 0}];
ReplaceAt[list, x_ :> Style[x, Red],  positions] // MatrixForm
(* Output *)
```

[image]

```
(* Path *)
gg = GridGraph[{dim, dim}];
path = DirectedEdge @@@ 
   Partition[dim (#[[1]] - 1) + #[[2]] & /@ positions , 2, 1];

res = Graph[Join[gg // EdgeList, path]
   , VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[dim^2] -> (Rotate[#, 90 °] & /@ 
        Flatten[ReplaceAt[list, x_ :> Style[x, Red],  positions]])]
   ,  VertexCoordinates -> Thread[VertexList@gg -> 
      AbsoluteOptions[gg, VertexCoordinates][[1, 2]]]
   , VertexLabels -> Automatic
   , EdgeStyle -> Gray];

Rotate[Rasterize[
  HighlightGraph[res, path, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Dotted"], 
  ImageResolution -> 300], -90 °]
(* Output *)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are good ways to visualize presented so far. This answer just gives an alternative way to get the path, trying to be more efficient for very large lists:

```
path[list_] := Module[{bag = CreateDataStructure["HashSet"], n},
  Reap[
    Do[n = TakeSmallest[
        Select[row, e |-> ! bag["MemberQ", e] || e == 0], 
        UpTo[2]][[-1]];
      Sow[n]; bag["Insert", n]
    , {row, list}]
    ][[2, 1]]]

path[list]
(* {1,3,2,0,7,0} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `FoldPairList`:**

```
list = {{0, 1, 4, 8, 9, 1}, {0, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3}, {0, 8, 6, 1, 3, 
    2}, {0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1}, {0, 2, 9, 2, 7, 3}, {0, 2, 1, 7, 2, 3}};

fplist = FoldPairList[{Min@Rest@First@#, 
     DeleteCases[Rest@#, Min@Rest@First@#, {2}]} &, list, 
   ConstantArray[1, Length@list]] /. ∞ -> 0
```

> {1, 3, 2, 0, 7, 0}

```
pos = Transpose[{Range@Length@list, 
   MapThread[Sequence @@ FirstPosition[#1, #2] &, {list, fplist}]}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 1}}

---

*Visualization*:

```
MapAt[Style[#1, Red, 16, Bold] &, list, pos] // MatrixForm
```

[image]